# Linq OrderByDescending with inline comparer function

Tags: vb.net, linq, visual-studio

Suppose I have a custom object stored in a list and I'd like to sort it based upon the absolute value of one of its properties (stored as a double).

In my code I have this:

```
MyList.Sort(Function(ob1, ob2) Math.Abs(ob1.Val).CompareTo(Math.Abs(ob2.Val)))
```

Which works perfectly! - But now I want to sort it **in descending order**.

I know linq has the `OrderByDescending`, but I can't seem to get it to work with a in-line comparer function. How would that look? Or is there another, easier way too?

Comment: A simple solution is to swap the arguments: `obj1 CompareTo obj2` is ascending and  `obj2 CompareTo obj1` is descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
MyList = MyList.OrderByDescending(Function(ob) Math.Abs(ob.Val)).ToList()
```

Unlike `Sort`, `OrderByDescending` does not sort the list in place.  Also, the function just needs to return the sort key for each item.

**Update**

I missed the overload of `OrderByDescending` that takes an `IComparer`, so you could also do something like this:

```
MyList = MyList.OrderByDescending(
    Function(ob) ob.Val,
    Comparer(Of Double).Create(
        Function(key1, key2) Math.Abs(key1).CompareTo(Math.Abs(key2))
    )
).ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mark, that worked perfectly!! - Between your idea and @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå's, I got it!!. **THANK YOU** for saving me a whole bunch of time fighting!!!